# com.android.support:design:24.1.0 didn't display correctly in navigation bar

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-support-library

I have updated my dependencies to the following:

com.android.support:design:24.0.0 --> com.android.support:design:24.1.0
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 --> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0

I updated as well the build tools to version 24.0.1.

However after that, my navigation drawer looks not good, as you can see here:
[image]

With the old version it looks like that:

[image]

Do you have any idea what this error is or it is the new standard?

Thanks for every response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it's a bug in new android support design library, check [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216465) in AOSP issue tracker, as mentioned there is a bug with checked item background - it uses `colorPrimaryDark`.

Until it would be fixed I've found probably ugly and maybe **irrelevant** in the future, but simple workaround - `NavigationView` uses `colorPrimaryDark` to highlight item background, so we can just override its `android:theme` with changed `colorPrimaryDark` to the one that we need, in our case it's gray.

So, **firstly** add a new style to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="NavigationViewGraySelectorTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- Extract this color to colors.xml -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ddd</item>
</style>
```

And then simply use it in your `NavigationView` widget:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationViewGraySelectorTheme"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_view_icon_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_view_text_color"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

As Chris Banes mentioned in the [AOSP issue thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216465#c13), the issue will be fixed with the ***24.1.1*** version of support library release.

Comment: I have approximately similar problem. Selections in my navigation drawer are done with colorAccent instead of colorPrimaryDark, but this solution does not work for me. I added NavigationViewGraySelectorTheme in styles.xml and v21\styles.xml and changed theme for NavigationView, but it still fills selected item completely with app's colorAccent. I tried mentioning both colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent in NavigationViewGraySelectorTheme